# How can I select elements from an NSArray according to array of NSIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsindexpath, nsindexset

Is there a fast way to get all elements at indexes from an array returned from a `UITableView` (`NSArray` of `NSIndexPaths`).

For instance:

```
[self.dataSourceArray selectItemsAt:[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedItems]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fast"? Shortest code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in method, but you can simply loop over the selected rows
(assuming that there is only one section) and add the corresponding elements
to a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *selectedObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
    [selectedObjects addObject:self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `objectsAtIndexes:` method of NSArray.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *mutableIndexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

// Add all indexes to NSMutableIndexSet
for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows].count; i++) {
    [mutableIndexSet addIndex: ((NSIndexPath *) [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows][i]).row];
}

[self.dataSourceArray objectsAtIndexes:mutableIndexSet];
```

Comment: `objectsAtIndexes:` takes an `NSIndexSet` as parameter.

Comment: What is the advantage of creating an index set first? You can directly add the selected items to a mutable array in the loop.

Comment: @MartinR Because `objectsAtIndexes:` asks for `NSMutableIndexSet`, not `NSArray`.

Answer (score -1):

word you are looking for is Lambda

there is two methots for that

you can look for it in link

[Does Objective-C have List Lambda Query like C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648822/does-objective-c-have-list-lambda-query-like-c)

it should look like this

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
       for(NSIndexPath i in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedItems]){
                if(i.row == evaluatedObject.row){
                   return YES;
                }
        }
       return NO;
}];
NSArray *result = [self.dataSourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Comment: That's a little vague as an answer for this question. Can you elaborate a bit or post an example?